# How to change player objects when switching scenes?

Tags: unity, mirror-networking

I have a scene for lobby. When player connects to server he gets a lobbyCharacter, which is an empty gameobject with a script on it that create UI element with the players name. In lobby players can select character they want to use.

Now when starting game, i would like to switch scene to the game scene when all players are ready. I have been reading the API, documentation, and different stack questions, but i cant seem to find any info on how this should work. On NetworkManager i can do scene schange which will be changed on all clients. But how do i persist data over multiple scenes? And if the lobby characters are destroyied how are the game characters instansiated according to the choises made in lobby? How does the client connection persist between multiple scenes?

Do i just manage the character locally and use syncHooks to synchronize over the server? Do i need to create somesort of container gameobject that holds the player connection information and some extra stuff?

EDIT

Reading the soruce code of mirror i fouind that NetworkManager holds the connection of the client, sort of. So now the issue has come down to replacing the prefab for the connection.

I have the following code:

```
 public void switchScene()
    {
        GameObject obj = NetworkClient.connection.identity.gameObject;

        NetworkServer.ReplacePlayerForConnection(NetworkClient.connection, Instantiate(shipPrefab));

        NetworkServer.Destroy(obj);
        ServerChangeScene(gameScene);
    }
```

This should switch the prefab for connection and then switch scene, but i keep getting error

```
InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
Mirror.NetworkIdentity.SetClientOwner (Mirror.NetworkConnection conn) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkIdentity.cs:362)
Mirror.NetworkServer.InternalReplacePlayerForConnection (Mirror.NetworkConnection conn, UnityEngine.GameObject player, System.Boolean keepAuthority) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkServer.cs:837)
Mirror.NetworkServer.ReplacePlayerForConnection (Mirror.NetworkConnection conn, UnityEngine.GameObject player, System.Boolean keepAuthority) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkServer.cs:697)
LobbyManager.switchScene () (at Assets/LobbyManager.cs:51)
```

And i dont understand why this is happening. New prefab has networkIdentity and networkTransform. Old prefab only has network transform. Up until this point everything wors, but once i want to switch scenes, it breaks.

Comment: How have you tried applying [past Q&A about persisting data between scenes in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+between+scenes) to this situation? Did you run into any particular snag making those past answers work for your needs?

Comment: After investigating the mirror-network sourcecode I understand that the NEtworkManager itself holds the connection of the client. But now i have the issue of switching player character,

Comment: There is even an example in the mirror project that includes a lobby system that does exactly what you are trying to achieve. It is called `Room`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. You will have to get a `networkbehaviour` on your player with `GetComponent` and take the `connectionToClient`. Only works when your `switchScene()` is running on the server, obviously.

Comment: So i need to tell the server to switch scene. So if server does it i can can rebind everything i want.